# How to fix 'window.minimize() is not a function'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6, electron

so I'm fairly new to javascript and electron.
I created a frameless window and added a bar with 3 buttons (minimize, maximize and close).

```
<div class="menu-buttons">
      <button id="window-minimize" class="menu-button"></button>
      <button id="window-maximize" class="menu-button"></button>
      <button id="window-close" class="menu-button">✕</button>
</div>
```

Also I added the script menubar.js:

```
const $ = require('jquery')
const { remote } = require('electron')

var window = remote.getCurrentWindow()

$('#window-minimize').click(() => {
    window.maximize()
})

$('#window-maximize').click(() => {
    if(!window.isMaximized()) {
        window.maximize()
    } else {
        window.unmaximize()
    }
})

$('#window-close').click(() => {
    window.close()
})
```

Now my problem is that the close button works perfectly fine, but the rest of the window methods return the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.isMaximized is not a function
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (menubar.js:11)

So I'm not sure why the close button works and the other methods won't work.

Comment: Change the name of the `window` variable -> https://github.com/mawie81/electron-window-state/issues/3#issuecomment-375772727

Comment: Uff. Thanks a lot, that worked. Sorry for that simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Use `windowState`:

```
if (window.windowState == 1) //Window is maximized
if (window.windowState == 2) //Window is minimized
if (window.windowState == 3) //Window is at normal size
if (window.windowState == 4) //Window is full screen
```

Comment: Okay I tried that. It fixes the problem about window.isMaximized() is not a function. But still window.maximize() and window.minimize() are still not recorgnised as functions.

Answer (score 0):

Within electron `window` defines the global scope, `window.close()` will still work as it is a function within that scope.

Try doing `console.log(window);` to see what exactly I mean.

To fix this, you should rename **your** `window` variable to something else. Example:

```
var win = remote.getCurrentWindow();
```

Hope this helped.

-Josh